# Error handling with AlamofireObjectMapper vs Alamofire + ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

Currently I'm Using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) + [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). I want to use [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) instead. 
But i have 1 issue: **how to deal with api-content-level error?**

for example when i try to save a new user:
if all details i sent to the server are valid so my server returns the new user details as json.
but if i'm sending wrong details (at the app logic level) the api will return a json with just an error message like "this user name already taken"

currently i'm using Alamofire to return json:

```
Alamofire.request(myURL, method: .post, parameters: dic, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {

                            callback(JSON)

                    } else {
                        print("error with response.result.value")}

                case .failure:

                    debugPrint(request)
                    //alert to user 

                }

            }
```

And then, in the callback, i check the json to see if it looks like a user structure or an error structure (if it is a user structure i use ObjectMapper to make it a User object):

```
MyAPI.saveUser(user){
                    (response) in

                    // response to json (to check error)
                    if (MyAPI.JSONToDictionary(response)!)["error"] != nil{

                        // Application level error (logic)
                        print((MyAPI.JSONToDictionary(response)!)["error"])

                    }
                    else{

                        //Using ObjectMapper - response to User object 
                        let responsedUser = MyAPI.jsonToUser(response)

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "userDetailsSegue", sender: self)

                    }
                }
```

Question is: AlamofireObjectMapper is mapping the response directly to a user. how can i check the if the mapping was succeful and handle the case it didn't? how can i get the error message my server sends?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?